# elasticsearch-hadoop 1.3 M3 proxy support not working

Tags: hadoop, nginx, proxy, elasticsearch, apache-pig

i am a beginner in elasticsearch and hadoop. i am having a problem with moving data from hdfs into elasticsearch server using es.net.proxy.http.host with credentials. Server secured with credentials using nginx proxy configuration. But when i am trying to move data using pig script it shows null pointer exception.

My pig script is

**REGISTER elasticsearch-hadoop-1.3.0.M3/dist/elasticsearch-hadoop-1.3.0.M3.jar**

**A = load 'date' using PigStorage() as (date:datetime);**

**store A into 'doc/id' using org.elasticsearch.hadoop.pig.EsStorage('es.net.proxy.http.host=ipaddress','es.net.proxy.http.port=portnumber','es.net.proxy.http.user=username','es.net.proxy.http.pass=password');**

I don't understand where is the problem with my script. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this type of problem.elasticsearch-hadoop-1.3.0.M3.jar should not support the Proxy and authentication setting.You will try to elasticsearch-hadoop-1.3.0.BUILDSHAPSHOT.jar file. But I couldn't move object data like Totuble to Production server with authentication

Thank U